# Can't import module / library in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, node-modules, package.json

So i installed a slider library called hooper in VueJS 3, and i import it in my local like this

```
<template>
  <hooper>
    <slide>1</slide>
    <slide>1</slide>
    <slide>1</slide>
    <slide>1</slide>
    <slide>1</slide>
  </hooper>
</template>
<script>
 import { Hooper, Slide } from 'hooper'
 import 'hooper/dist/hooper.css'

 export default {
  components: {
    Hooper, Slide
  }
 }
</script>
```

Also i can't import **hooper** (import { Hooper, Slide } from **'hooper'**)
There are three dots under the word hoope, and it says:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'hooper'. 'c:/Users/nurdi/pkl/template/java-vibes/node_modules/hooper/dist/hooper.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.


Try `npm i --save-dev @types/hooper` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'hooper';`Vetur(7016)
```

Also there is an error on the console, it says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is not a constructor
at eval (hooper.esm.js?7e04:172:1)
at Module../node_modules/hooper/dist/hooper.esm.js (chunk-vendors.js:1393:1)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849:30)
at fn (app.js:151:20)
at eval (GuestBook.vue?ed46:64:1)
at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js?!./src/components/GuestBook.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (app.js:986:1)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849:30)
at fn (app.js:151:20)
at eval (GuestBook.vue?9b66:1:1)
at Module../src/components/GuestBook.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (app.js:1840:1)
```

Comment: It looks like you're using typescript? The error is a type issue

Comment: im not using typescript, its only vue3 with js

Comment: The error is a typescript error.

Comment: Yeah but i don't even know or use typescript in my code..

Comment: I just created a fresh vue3 project, installed the dependency, and used your component code, and I do not get any errors. Something else must be causing it to think you're using TS? Does the project have a `tsconfig.json` file for instance?

Comment: I don't know but [that lib](https://github.com/baianat/hooper) looks like Vue 2 only (no new version released since Jul 3, 2019)

Comment: @MichalLevý isn't Vue3 backwards compatible with Vue2?

Comment: In terms of "user" API mostly yes, but it has a lot of breaking changes affecting libraries/plugins

Comment: I don't have tsconfig.json because i dont use typescript.. Also i don't think the library vue version has a lot to do with this case, because on my last project i used vueperslides and it worked. I just doing the same thing, before i use hooper on this project i use vueperslides too and i got the same error..

Comment: But you might be rigth - it is not using any `Vue.use()` (plugin features) so it might be ok. Anyway 1st error is from VS Code plugin Vetur and is not a real problem

Comment: The 1st error "Could not find a declaration....", when i open my localhost it just show blank white screen and the console shows that.

Comment: @RadhifAzli my local version also gets that error.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple issues in your file:

- `Could not find a declaration file [..]` is a Typescript error, which is probably happening because the Vue CLI comes with TS out of the box. If you don't use TS, change `<script>` to `<script lang="js">`. I recommend always doing this either way.
- Import vue and change `export default {}` `export default Vue.extend({})` to let the app know it's a Vue component.
- `Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is not a constructor` usually means a default import could not be found in the file you're referencing. Since you're not trying to import a module default, I can only hope that one of the previous two issues is the cause of this. It could very well be that this issue lies within the library itself.

P.S. I'm used to coding in Vue 2, so it's possible that some of my suggestions don't apply the exact same way in Vue 3.